# Should we give concrete examples when tasking in TDD?

Tags: tdd, task

Here takes the "taximeter" requirement as example. Say we have go an simple requirement from client:

> If the distance is <= 2.0km, the price is $6 fixed. After that, the charge of every km should be $0.8, and the final result should be rounded

Now I want to develop this requirement in TDD and I should split it into small tasks, and write them on paper. I have several different versions, but not sure which is the best

### version 1, simplest

1. the starting fare is fixed
2. after starting fare distance, every km have fixed charge
3. the final price should be rounded

### version 2, give some concrete numbers appears in the requirement

1. the starting fare is fixed $6 for distance <= 2km
2. after starting fare distance, every km have fixed charge $0.8
3. the final price should be rounded

### version 3, with some examples

1. the starting fare is fixed $6 for distance <= 2km
   e.g. 0km == $6, 2km == $6
2. after starting fare distance, every km have fixed charge $0.8
   e.g. 3km == $6.8, 10km == $12.4
3. the final price should be rounded 
   e.g. $4 => $4, $4.49 => $4, $4.5 => $5

I'm not sure which one is the best as a task in TDD, is there any principles, examples or best practise?

Comment: If the example adds clarity to the specification, then it's worth adding.  Purely implementing V1 wouldn't match the client requirements. V2 is closer, but misses information, like what the price should be rounded to.  V3 removes some ambiguity through the example for 3, but this could have been done with a more precise V2.

Answer (score 2):

Writing a list of tasks is simply a reminder list to help guide your TDD session, so the first version is a good example of that.  Obviously, as you start each task, you will look at the requirement to get the actual numbers you'll need for your tests.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I get the point of writing the tasks out on paper (or anywhere else). Why not just write them as unit tests? No sense in duplicating the the effort.

Between the selections, it's a toss up between v2 and v3. It would depend on where the example numbers came from. If the examples come from the users, then I like v3.